# Equivalent definition of almost geometric quotient

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory

I am trying to prove the following lemma -

**Lemma** - Let $X$ be a variety and let $G$ be an algebraic group acting algebraically on $X$. Let $\pi:X\rightarrow X//G$ be a good categorical quotient. Then the following are equivalent:

1. $X$ has a $G$ - invariant Zariski dense open subset $U_0$ such that $G\cdot x$ is closed in $X$ for all $x\in U_0$
2. $X//G$ has a Zariski dense open subset $U$ such that $\pi|_{\pi^{-1}(U)}:\pi^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U$ is a geometric quotient.

I have managed to prove $1\Rightarrow 2$. For $2\Rightarrow 1$ here is my attempt -

Let $U_0=\pi^{-1}(U)$. Since $\pi|_{U_0}:U_0\rightarrow U$ is a geometric quotient we have that $U_0$ is $G$ - invariant and $G\cdot x$ is closed in $U_0$ for all $x\in U_0$. From here on I'm stuck.

(a) Why is $G\cdot x$ closed in $X$?

(b) Why is $U_0$ dense? I can show it is dense if $\pi$ is open but How would I show $\pi$ is open?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your base field? Is $G$ assumed connected?

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain The base field is $\mathbb{C}$. $G$ is not assumed connected.

Comment: For (a): You have that $U_0=\pi^{-1}(U)$. Let $x\in U_0$ and $y\in \overline{Gx}$ (the closure in $X$). Then, by definition of the quotient, $\pi(y)=\pi(x)$ and therefore you have $y\in\pi^{-1}(\pi(x))\subseteq \pi^{-1}(U)$. Since $y$ was arbitrary, you have $\overline{Gx}\subseteq U_0$ and since $Gx$ was already closed in $U$, we have $\overline{Gx}=Gx$. I'm a bit stuck with (b) right now, and I have an appointment in 5 ... I'll look at it again soon.

Comment: @Jesko Huttenhain, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a): You have that $U_0=\pi^{-1}(U)$. Let $x\in U_0$ and $y\in \overline{Gx}$ (the closure in $X$). Then, by definition of the quotient, $\pi(y)=\pi(x)$ and therefore you have $y\in\pi^{-1}(\pi(x))\subseteq \pi^{-1}(U)=U_0$. Since $y$ was arbitrary, you have $\overline{Gx}\subseteq U_0$ and since $Gx$ was already closed in $U$, we have $\overline{Gx}=Gx$.

For (b): Note that since $U_0$ is $G$-invariant, so is $Z:=\overline{U_0}$. We want to show that $Z=X$. Let $I$ be the ideal sheaf of $Z$ in $X$. We want to show that it is the zero sheaf. If it were not, then since $Z$ is $G$-invariant, so is $I$ and we may pick an open, $G$-invariant subset $V\subseteq X$ such that $I(V)$ contains a nonzero element $f$. Hence, $f\in\mathcal O_X(U)^G$ and $f(U_0)=0$. Since $\pi$ is a good quotient, we have $f=\pi^\sharp(\tilde f)$ and $\tilde f(U)=\tilde f(\pi(U_0))=f(U_0)=0$. Since $U$ is dense in $X/\!\!/G$, this means that $\tilde f=0$. Consequently, $f=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to do it without using the ideal sheaf?

Comment: @Rise: Well, notation would be lighter if $X$ was affine, and the problem is trivial if $X$ is irreducible. Is any of that the case? If not, then at some point I am sure you will have to use the fact that the quotient is good. What is your definition of a "good" quotient, if not via $G$-invariant sections?

Comment: $X$ is not affine. The definition of good quotient is the following - $f:X\to Y$ is constant on $G$ - orbits and 1. If $U\subseteq Y$ is open then the $O_Y(U)\to O_X(f^{-1}(U))$ induces an isomorphism $O_Y(U)$ and $O_X(f^{-1}))^G$. 2. If $W\subseteq X$ is closed invariant then $f(W)$ is closed. 3. Closed disjoint invariant sets in $X$ are disjoint in $Y$.

Comment: Why is it trivial if $X$ is irreducible?

Comment: Any nonempty open subset of an irreducible variety is dense.

Comment: Oops! I forgot that simple fact. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: @Rise: I thought I had a more geometric proof using your definition, but it doesn't quite work. Maybe I will come up with something better.